# torch concat 1D to a 2D tensor

Tags: vector, pytorch, concatenation

I have a issue on concat 2 tensor,

say I have x and y:

```
x = torch.randn(35, 50)
y = torch.randn(35)
```

How do I concat every y value in to x[0] to make x has a shape 35,51?

I tried:

```
for i in y:
    for a in range(x.shape[0]):
        x[a] = torch.cat((x[a],i),0)
```

Still getting shape error. Any smart way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```py
z = torch.cat([x,y.reshape(-1,1)], axis=1)
print(z.shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([35, 51])
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to concat a torch array of (8000, 35, 1) with (8000, 35, 50)? I tried the for low but it does not work

Comment: @NathanChan I assume you intend to get a tensor of size `[8000,35,51]`. Let `a=torch.randn(8000,35,1)` and `b=torch.randn(8000,35,50)`. Now use `c=torch.cat([a,b], dim=2)` and get `c.shape` is `[8000,35,51]`. Hope that helps.